# this.funtionName is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am learing to use API an making a news website where you can search a term. I am using the code given below to do so.

```
var newsAccordion = document.getElementById("newsAccordion");

let news = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxx",
  fetchNews: function () {
    fetch(
      "https://gnews.io/api/v4/top-headlines?&country=in&lang=en&token=xxxxxxxxxxx"
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.fetchCotent(data);
      });
  },
  fetchCotent: (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    size = data.articles.length;
    let newsHtml = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      const { title } = data.articles[i];
      const { publishedAt } = data.articles[i];
      const { url } = data.articles[i];
      const { image } = data.articles[i];
      const { description } = data.articles[i];
      console.log(title, publishedAt);

      var date = new Date(publishedAt).toLocaleString(undefined, {
        timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata",
      });
    }
    newsAccordion.innerHTML = newsHtml;
  },
  searchNews: (term) => {
    console.log(term);
    fetch(
      "https://gnews.io/api/v4/search?&lang=en&q=" +
        term +
        "&token=xxxxxxxxxx"
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
               this.serchNews();
            });
  },
  searchNews: (term) => {
      //code goes here
};

document
  .querySelector(".search button")
  .addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    news.searchNews(document.querySelector(".search-bar").value);
  });

window.onload = function () {
  news.fetchNews();
};
```

But the problem is its gaving an error sying

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: showSearch is not defined
> at index.js:59

At index.js:59 it says:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.showSearch is not a function

My question is why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Which lang is it, 2nd where is the rest of the code, the only code we see is the function you have written, where and which file are you calling it.. and many more question before we can suggest any solution

Comment: @NishantShamVispute The language is javascript. The rest of the code would be too long and it would not allow me to post such long code here, I have problem only in this specific part. Why is it saying that the function is not defined even if I have done so?

Comment: `this` might not be what you think it is. Try `console.log(this)` before that line.

Comment: `const showSearch = (data) => { }`

just replace colon with equals

Comment: because this points to context of enclosing function where you defined the object containing your `searchNews` and `showSearch` properties. So if you define `showSearch` outside of the current object, the issue will be resolved.

Comment: The problem as I see it is not within this part of the code.. because this part is only the definition of the actual function, the error you are getting is either in the ```index.js``` file or some other place which is called from inside of ```index.js```

Comment: @Vishwak You can't put variable assignments inside object literals.

Comment: What is the name of the object containing above piece of code?

Comment: How do you call `searchNews`?

Comment: @VLAZ With this function 

 document
  .querySelector(".search button")
  .addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    news.searchNews(document.querySelector(".search-bar").value);
  });

Comment: @NishantShamVispute This is excrept from index.js only

Comment: Can you post the Complete Error log to your question.. this much code is not providing any insight

Comment: @NishantShamVispute I have done already... thats all the error I am getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the misunderstanding of this in Javascript. Please read the [this in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Anyway you can modify the code as follows.

```
const obj = {

  searchNews: (term) => {
    console.log(term);
    function cbFunc(data) {
      this.showSearch(data);
    }
    fetch(
      "https://gnews.io/api/v4/search?&lang=en&q=" +
        term +
        "&token=368ddd2e4d1c1c559f1fb904cb1e09fa"
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(cbFunc.bind(obj));
  },
  showSearch: (data) => {
    size = data.articles.length;
    let newsHtml = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      const { title } = data.articles[i];
      const { publishedAt } = data.articles[i];
      const { url } = data.articles[i];
      const { image } = data.articles[i];
      const { description } = data.articles[i];

      var date = new Date(publishedAt).toLocaleString(undefined, {
        timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata",
      });

      console.log(title, date, url, image, description);
    }
  }
}
```

Please place emphasis on bind call, where obj should be your wrapper object(at the top line of the code).

Answer (score 1):

Replace `arrow` function to `regular` function for `searchNews` and `showSearch`. So that it gets the current scope using this, because arrow function doesn't have it's own context; it takes the context of enclosing function.

```
searchNews: function(term) {
    console.log(term);
    fetch(
      "https://gnews.io/api/v4/search?&lang=en&q=" +
        term +
        "&token=368ddd2e4d1c1c559f1fb904cb1e09fa"
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.showSearch(data);
      });
  },
  showSearch: function(data) {
    size = data.articles.length;
    // your code...
  },
```

> Working code example:

```js
const news = {
    searchNews: function (term) {
        console.log("search news: ", term);
        fetchApi("https://gnews.io/api/v4/search")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
              console.log("received data:");
              this.showSearch(data);
            });
    },
    showSearch: function (data) {
        console.log("showSearch: ", data);
        // your code...
    }
}

function fetchApi(url) { // fetch api stub
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const response = {
            data: { id: 123, title: "test-title" },
            statusCode: 200
        }
        let responseObj = new Response(JSON.stringify(response))
        setTimeout(resolve(responseObj), 500);
    })
}

document.querySelector("#search-button").addEventListener("click", function (e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); 
  news.searchNews(document.querySelector("#search-bar").value); 
});
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div>Enter search title: 
<input type="text" id="search-bar">
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 20px">
<button id="search-button">Search News</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry... but this didn't work

Comment: this is working i can show you by stubing the fetchApi()

Comment: But not for me.

Comment: @RahulKumar your code is correct, but we are missing the context here, the question only show the 2 fn() and error line with no prior context.. these 2 fn() might be wrapped inside another fn or maybe a 3rd asyn fn is calling showSearch with this pointing to that scope..

Comment: @BIJANROY mention the required code in your post which contains the current piece of code. i mean definition of current object.

Comment: @NishantShamVispute, It's wrapped inside a news object as `searchNews` and `showSearch` functions are comma separated. and yes i agree that wrapper code is missing, asked the same in above comment.

Comment: I have changed the code. And have given the full script. Please check now.

Comment: updated the answer above and it works on click of search button

Comment: Ahh now its much clearer and also @RahulKumar answer should work..